# Esconder Div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer para se houver valor ocorrer um display none em todas as divs com carro?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".acionador").click(function() {
        if($(".texto").html().indexOf("carro")!=-1) {
            // fazer um hide em todas as divs que contem carro
        }
    });
}); 
</script>

<div class="acionador" style="background: black; color: white;">acionador</div>

<div class="texto"> texo carro </div>
<div class="texto"> texo carro </div>
<div class="texto"> texo moto </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o seletor `contains`:

```
$("div.texto:contains('carro')").hide();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".acionador").click(function() {
    $("div.texto:contains('carro')").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="acionador" style="background: black; color: white;">acionador</div>

<div class="texto"> texto carro </div>
<div class="texto"> texto carro </div>
<div class="texto"> texto moto </div>
```

Comment: Otimo! não conhecia esse contains :)

Comment: @Josimara apesar de não ter o `contains` listado, [segue aqui uma lista de 30 seletores úteis](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048).

Comment: como especifico a div por classe ou id ai?

Comment: @Josimara por classe você utiliza o `.`, como no exemplo `div.texto`. Por `id` você utiliza o `#`, ficando algo como `div#texto1`

Comment: Sorack, há tanto tempo...

Comment: @Miguel hahaha tava namorando, aí não dava tempo. Agora tomei um pé na bunda e to mais disponível

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o método *each* do jQuery para iterar com todas as ocorrências da classe texto por exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".acionador").click(function() {
        $(".texto").each(function() {
            if($(this).html().indexOf("carro")!=-1) {
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    });
});
```